# Replicate/synchronize backend instances across regions in Google Cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, synchronization, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, replication

I set up Cross-Region Load Balancing in Google Cloud and is working fine. 
How can I replicate/synchronize the back-end instances to have the exact same content (now each instance has it's own content) ? What should i search for ?

P.S.: i want the behavior of "Managed instance group" but cross region. Load-balance multiple instances on different regions, all with the same content.

Answer (score -2):

There are 3 types of global load balancing (cross multiple regions) on GCE:

- [HTTP(S) LB](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/), working at L7 - HTTP(S) layer.
- [SSL Proxy LB](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/tcp-ssl/), working at L3 - SSL layer.
- [TCP Proxy LB](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/tcp-ssl/tcp-proxy), working at L3 - TCP layer.

Just use the same instance template for all the managed instance groups.

Comment: I forgot to mention HTTP load balancing. I've read the docs but how can i replicate the content in real time between the instance groups. I don't see a master/slave architecture. I want all the managed instance groups to have the same content all the time.

Comment: Is the content read-only static files? There are many ways to share states across instances, depending on the nature of your "content". Cloud Storage for files, BigTable,  Spanner for databases.

Comment: If you use an instance template and set up a unique DB with proxy connections where you store all your data, you should not have a desync problem.